# What's the importance of / in the following Linux command

Tags: linux

What's the difference between

```
cd abc/xyz/
```

and

```
cd abc/xyz
```

What's the importance of `/` at the end? Which is the right way of using it? Because both seem to work properly.

Comment: title should have s/Doubt/Question/, or should be the first line of the quesiton

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference may be minor in the `cd` example you provided, but beware when you `mv` files.

For example if you want to move several files to another directory, and you type

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do mv $i dest ;  done
```

Forgetting the trailing slash, then *each* of the files moved will overwrite a file called  `dest` (the first will actually *create* a file called `dest` if it doesn't already exist). The result is that all files except the last are overwritten with the last file, and it's now called `dest`.

To *move* to a directory, you must specify the trailing /

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do mv $i dest/ ;  done
```

One side effect of the slash is that if the directory doesn't exist, you'll get an error message.

Comment: Yes.  This isn't an issue of pathname resolution, though, it's how an ambiguity in the specification of `mv` gets resolved in practice.  Likewise the issue with `rsync`.

Comment: "To move to a directory, you must specify the trailing /".  No you don't.  It is simply a safety trick in case the directory does not exist, which works since "dest/" is (as I write in my answer below) equivalent to "dest/.", which will be an invalid path if "dest" is not a directory.  The slash it not needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd abc/xyz
```

Is correct, since "abc/xyz" refers to '*the "xyz" entity in the "abc" directory*'.  When you type

```
cd abc/xyz/
```

it refers to '*The "" entity in the "xyz" directory in the "abc" directory*'.  The "" (empty string) entity gets automatically translated to ".", which is the "current" directory, which in this case is the "xyz" directory.  So it all works out to the same thing.

(Some people feel that directories "*must*" have a slash appended.  They are mistaken.)

Comment: s/must/should/ ...

Answer (score 2):

```
cd abc/xyz/
```

is the correct way of doing it.  But if you specify

```
cd abc/xyz
```

and if cd figures out that xyz is a directory,  it assumes the presence of the trailing /

Comment: There is no reason to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical.  The string is treated by the filename operators as a "path" which is an abstraction, and each path is associated with a basename and another path, the dirname.  Two paths are identical if each of these are the same string.  For your example:

```
cas var$ dirname abc/xyz; basename abc/xyz
abc
xyz
cas var$ dirname abc/xyz/; basename abc/xyz/
abc
xyz
```

Note that, while some programs treat strings identically, including all the usual UNIX utilities, if they are the same paths, there are others that do care about trailing slashes.  The most important of these is `rsync`.

**Postscript** 
From the POSIX spec, [Pathname Resolution](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

> A pathname that contains at least one non-slash character and that ends with one or more trailing slashes shall be resolved as if a single dot character ( '.' ) were appended to the pathname.

Comment: so to interpolate from your postscript, the example `abc/xyz/` is actually interpreted (under POSIX) as `abc/xyz/.`.  (Teddy made this point in his answer as well, but thanks for providing a source.)